# How to edit new messages before forwarding using python

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, forwarding

I am using a Python code to forward new messages between two bot/channel telegram.
I am trying to edit messages before forwarding them (I need to delete some parts of text), but I didn't find the right solution

This is my code to forward new messages:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, 
events
import asyncio

api_id = 99999999
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

my_channel_id = -10000000000000
channels = [-1000000000000]

client = TelegramClient('myGrab', api_id, api_hash)
print("GRAB - Started")

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channels))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if event.message:
        await client.send_message(my_channel_id, event.message)


client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

This is the source message:

```
The Button LTDSH 11 has matched with 
a live Match

Adelaide United ||(4) V NE MetroStars(1)
 Australia :- Npl South Australian
⏱ Elapsed Time: 55'
⚽️ Score: 1 - 1

Home Shots: on:off Target: 3:1
Away Shots: on:off Target: 2:7

Home Possession: 37%
Away Possession: 63%

Home Dangerous Attacks: 30
Away Dangerous Attacks: 39

AP1 (H:A): 27:33
Form (H:A): LLDLD:WWDWW

Home Corners: 2
Away Corners: 5

Last 10mins Shots on Target
Home:Away 1 : 0

Odds (H:D:A)
Starting 5.50 : 4.75 : 1.40
Live     8.50 : 4.33 : 1.33
```

And I'd like to delete some parts to get just this:

```
The Button LTDSH 11 has matched with a live Match

Adelaide United ||(4) V NE MetroStars(1)
 Australia :- Npl South Australian
⏱ Elapsed Time: 55'
⚽️ Score: 1 - 1

Odds (H:D:A)
Live     8.50 : 4.33 : 1.33
```

Any suggestion, please?

**EDIT:** the source text changes everytime, but there are some specific words in all messages. Is it possible to delete words/characters before or after a specific word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string manipulation to edit the message. This is the updated script:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import asyncio

api_id = 99999999
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

my_channel_id = -10000000000000
channels = [-1000000000000]

client = TelegramClient('myGrab', api_id, api_hash)
print("GRAB - Started")

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channels))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if event.message:
        original_message = event.message.message

        lines = original_message.split('\n')  # Split the source message into seperate lines
        new_message = '\n'.join(lines[:7]) + '\n\n' + lines[-2] # Keep the required parts and delete the rest

        await client.send_message(my_channel_id, new_message)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the event text and patch the edited text to it, the modifications will be saved and used when passed to send_message:

```py
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channels))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if event.message:
        old_message = event.text
        new_message = ...
        # do your edits however necessary.
        event.text = new_message

        await client.send_message(my_channel_id, event.message)
```

Comment: ok, but the source changes everytime, is it possible to edit event.text and delete, for example, characters/word after a specific word/character? Thanks

Comment: This answer is about the telethon part, only the where to modify, the how to modify needs more info, ask a seperate general python question and create regexes and split lines to produce the `new_message` however appropriate for your goals. if line numbers are consistent, a simple split("\n") and indexing by line numbers would do.

Comment: Ok, I see, I will open another question about regex ed split. Thanks